# PHP While loop only works for first two of three results?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I know I am a beginner, but I have an issue I can't figure out. I've searched everywhere. Please don't be mean:) I'm trying to learn!:)

SO I have a while loop that is making an HTML table for me, and two of the three row[] echoes work every time, but the third echoes only the ID of the last entry in the table.

My code:

```
<?php 
$searchsql = "SELECT * FROM `students` WHERE `fname` LIKE '%" . $searchvalue1 . "%' LIMIT 0, 10 ";
$search1result = mysql_query($searchsql);
while($search1row=mysql_fetch_array($search1result)){?>
<h3>
    <table align="center">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>First Name</td>
            <td>Last Name</td>
            <td>Select</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $search1row['fname'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $search1row['lname'];?></td>
            <td>
            <form method="post" action="4.php"> 
                <input type="hidden" id="voteid" name="voteid" class="inputbutton" value="<?php echo $search1row['studentid'];?>">
                <input type="submit" class="inputbutton" value="SELECT">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
</h3>
<?php }?>
```

So if the table returned is (see picture)

[image]

The select button from within that form always posts the studentid from the LAST row... Every select button posts Jane's ID number. So John, Jason, Jane, and their last names are echoed correctly, but their corresponding ID numbers are not... if that makes any sense.

I have to keep it a form because of the way my site works (not a link with get variables).

Any ideas on how to get the ID to echo inside of that form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not closing the form at the end of each loop. So each time the `voteid` input is getting overwritten which is why it always posts the id for the last row.

Add a closing form tag:

```
...
<form method="post" action="4.php"> 
    <input type="hidden" id="voteid" name="voteid" class="inputbutton" value="<?php echo $search1row['studentid'];?>">
    <input type="submit" class="inputbutton" value="SELECT">
</form>
...
```

Comment: Lol honest mistake - it only *seems* stupid after you figure what you were missing! Cheers :)